# Invalid icc profile: duplicate sequence numbers

Tags: java, imagem, processamento-de-imagens

Ao chamar `ImageIO.read` da imagem em anexo, ocorre o erro *Invalid icc profile: duplicate sequence numbers*. Código bem simples apenas fazendo:

```
File file = new File("C:\\temp\\imagem_java_teste.jpg");
FileInputStream input;
try {
    input = new FileInputStream(file);
    try {
        ImageIO.read(input);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

[image: Imagem que causa erro no Java, porém abre normal no Windows e em aplicativos de outras linguagens.]

Call stack:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Invalid icc profile: duplicate sequence numbers
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImageHeader(Native Method)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readNativeHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:532)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.checkTablesOnly(JPEGImageReader.java:277)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.gotoImage(JPEGImageReader.java:409)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:525)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:968)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:948)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1422)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1326)
    at Teste.main(Teste.java:22)
```

Comment: Peguei o seu código e adaptei para baixar a figura que está anexa a sua pergunta ao invés de abrir de um arquivo. E deu o mesmo erro.

Comment: que JDK está a usar?

Comment: Vale a pena dar uma olhada aqui: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/17992571/ - Linha 1285. Na linha 1280 está o bug que o Fabio Cardoso se refere.

Comment: Li noutro lado que desinstalar o JDK e voltar a instalar resolve o problema.

Comment: Estava com a jdk1.7.0_51, atualizei para a jdk1.7.0_80 e continua com o erro. Com a jre executando no cliente também ocorre o erro.